# Prevent insertText from placing text on previously inserted text?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a picture, for which I have the x and y coordinates for multiple objects. Each object has a name. I wish to use insertText to place the name in the middle of the object. Considering the large amount of objects per image, sometimes the text overlaps.

Currently, i use this which writes the text exactly to the middle.

```
I = imread(some_image.jpg);            % load image
for i = 1:length(object)               % for each object
    m = mean(object(i,1:2)));          % get the middle 
    I = insertText(I,m,[name]);        % and write label. 
end
```

What I want is a new label to be moved slightly, so that the newest label does not overlap with an old label.

Comment: The second argument to [`insertText`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/inserttext.html) is the position. You change that to change the position...

Comment: @excaza. Yes, but I don't know the size of the previous labels, and as a result I don't know the current boundaries of the existing labels.

Comment: Please see [mcve].

Comment: @excaza. Is there a way to create an example without copy-pasting the raw data?

Comment: There is no easy way. If you use a fixed-width font you can calculate box size based on the text length. Then you can use this length to detect whether there are any overlaps.